# send a post server and get the page and server sent, then parse in session

Tags: jsoup

```
try {
            org.jsoup.Connection.Response res = (org.jsoup.Connection.Response) Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .data(postParams)

                    .header(cookies1)

                    .header("Cache-Control", "private")
                    .header("Content-Length","")
                    .header("Accept-Language", "tr-TR,tr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3")
                    .header("Connection", "keep-alive")
                    .header("Cookie", "ASP.NET_SessionId=" + res1.cookie("ASP.NET_SessionId"))
                    .header("Host", "www.xxxxxxxxx.org")
                    .header("Referer", "http://www.xxxxxxx.org.tr/xxxxx.aspx")
                    .header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0")
                    .header("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")
                    .header("Location", "/xxxxxx.aspx")
                    .header("Server", "Microsoft-IIS/7.5")
                    .header("X-AspNet-Version", "4.0.30319")
                    .header("X-Powered-By", "ASP.NET")
                    .method(org.jsoup.Connection.Method.POST)
                    .execute();
```

i want to send a post server and get the page and server send the what i want to parse in session but i am getting error 500 could you help me about it

Answer (score 0):

Http 500 is an internal server error. What that means is the server itself if having issues processing the request. It would generally be up to the server hosts to inspect the log files to find the errors. However, in my experience incorrect formatting of the post request can yield such errors. Double check you are formatting your request correctly. It may be helpful to use a library such as Http Components by Apache to facilitate your post requests, and Jsoup to parse the returned information.